# Select image in android emulator gallery - Selenium With Java

Tags: java, android, selenium, android-emulator

I am trying to automate the android emulator image selection from gallery using appium with selenium Java.

The problem is that i could not select an image from the gallery from selenium Java.

I have pushed an  image named jerry.png to the android emulator sdcard - gallery.

I tried the below, but it doesnot work.

```
driver().findElement(By.id("com.android.graphics.drawable:id/jerry")).click();
```

How can i select an image in the android emulator gallery?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used coordinates to select the image,

```
HashMap<String, Double> map = new HashMap<String, Double>();
map.put("x", xCoordinate);
map.put("y", yCoordinate);
((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("mobile: tap", map);
```

Coordinates can be obtained by turning ON the options "Show Touch" and "Pointer Location" in the developer options in emualtor.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to get all image first in list array then you can click on particular , see below :

**FOR SINGLE IMAGE SELECTION**

```
List <WebElement> images = driver.findElements(By.xpath(YOUR IMAGE ID/XPATH));

System.out.println(images.size());

if(images.size()>0)
{

driver.findElement(By.xpath(YOUR IMAGE ID/XPATH)).click();}
```

**FOR MULTIPLE IMAGE SELECTION**

```
 List <WebElement> pics = driver.findElements(By.xpath(YOUR IMAGE ID/XPATH));

for(int x=0;x<5;x++)

{

    pics.get(x).click();


}
```

I recommend to use xpath to find images.

Comment: What will be xpath? i could not get the extact xpath to a image? Neither i could not get image id also? how can i do it?

Comment: try this xpath : //android.widget.GridView//android.widget.ImageView[1] which device you using?

Comment: I am using android emulator. device name is emulator 5554 with android version 4.4

Comment: //android.widget.GridView//android.widget.ImageView[1] is not work.. What will be resource id of an image in the gallery? any examples?

Comment: Here you will get resource id of gallery and then xpath of image...all image will have same resource id so I prefer xpath.

Comment: Do you using default android emulator OR genymotion OR real android device?

Comment: android emulator from android SDK

Comment: I have added screenshot of appium inspector to my question

Comment: I see , I dont think from here we can pick image because it has only 1 main view and for images there is no individual view...